# Compose into existing project, No virtual method Int

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Cant make compose run in existing kotlin/native project for month now, trying to set default Greeting example to splash instead of its ui, cant make it:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method Int$class-SplashActivity()I in class Lcom/a/b/c/activity/LiveLiterals$SplashActivityKt; or its super classes (declaration of 'a.b.c.ui.activity.LiveLiterals$SplashActivityKt' appears in /data/app/a.b.c.develop-7Zjdfjfy762lPctajg==/base.apk!classes29.dex)
    at a.b.c.ui.activity.SplashActivity.<clinit>
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1174)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2669)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Yes, crash before activity start.

kotlin 1.5.21

compose_version = 1.0.2

mTargetSdkVersion=30(I'm tired of merging manifests every sync, so no 31 until I'l run it all)

mCompileSdkVersion=31

mMinSdkVersion=21

**project level build.gradle:**

```
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0-alpha12"
    classpath "gradle.plugin.com.wiredforcode:gradle-spawn-plugin:0.8.2"
    classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10"
    classpath "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1"
```

**android module build.gradle(not whole file, its existing project):**

```
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0"
implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4"
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0"

implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.4.0-alpha02"
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0-alpha03"
implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-appcompat-theme:0.18.0"
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0-alpha03"

implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.0-alpha09"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0-alpha09"

implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0-beta01'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.4.0-beta01'

implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0-alpha02'

implementation "androidx.tracing:tracing-ktx:1.0.0"

implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"


implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.2"

also contains pushwoosh, appsflyer, crashlytics, junit tests(does impact compose libs?)
```

EDIT: pushwoosh, appsflyer, crashlytics was removed for sake of test, fixed nothing.

Downgrade to compose 1.0.1 and stable androidx did nothing

Comment: is splash activity added in your manifest?

Comment: @Ritt yes, existing project

Comment: Can you please share the code of Splash screen.

Comment: @RajshekharYadav it is empty, there is nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//contains 99% common code, now contains Compose view 
open class AppLegasyFlavorActivity

//absolutely empty for default flavor
class SplashActivity : AppLegasyFlavorActivity()
```

You can't have that for some reason with 1.0.2 compose. Your child must have onCreate overriden(even if its just super call). I removed legasy parent stuff, did flavors refactor and everything worked. This weird bug resulted as kotlin cant understand Int class. On the edge of technology ways, I guess.

Answer (score 5):

If you analyze the exception message closely, you might notice the mention of `LiveLiterals`:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method Int$class-SplashActivity()I in class Lcom/a/b/c/activity/**LiveLiterals**$SplashActivityKt;

The `LiveLiterals` part is not a part of your own API, but it's generated code by Compose, that enables the live editing of literals in the compose preview: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tooling#live-edit-literals

It seems that for one of your classes (in this case `SplashActivity`) the `LiveLiterals` support cannot be generated properly. I don't know if this  is a bug in Compose or a known limitation, but as a workaround there is a way to opt out of live literals: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/NoLiveLiterals

So if you have a class for which you get the NoSuchMethodError exception, add the `@NoLiveLiterals` annotation:

```
@NoLiveLiterals
class SplashActivity {
   // ...
```

The annotation may be added to a property, a function, a class or an entire file.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly same error with `io.insert-koin:koin-android:3.4.3` (also when adding Compose to the project).

In my case Compose/Koin had trouble with class:

```
class InAppImpl(val context: Context) : InApp, KoinComponent {
    private val preferences: SharedPreferences by inject()
// ...
}
```

I changed it to:

```
class InAppImpl(val context: Context, val preferences: SharedPreferences) : InApp {
// ...
}
```

And it solved the issue.

Thanks @Danilo Bargen for pointing into right direction as adding `@NoLiveLiterals` also worked in my case (but it is a workaround and not a true solution).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue in the issue tracker, plus a bunch of workarounds (the cleanest is maybe renaming files in your main source set e.g. `CommonSomeModule.kt` leaving `SomeModule.kt` for the flavors).

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/196063128

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that your compile SDK is 31, you are targetting API 31 (Android 12) and not setting the exported attribute.

You need to specify `android:exported="true"` in the manifest.

> If your app targets Android 12 and contains activities, services, or
> broadcast receivers that use intent filters, you must explicitly
> declare the android: exported attribute for these app components.

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Demo.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

For more info check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#security).

Comment: as I said, I'm tired of merging manifests, that's why its 30 now, means it was 31, means everything was marked as exported=true in manifest before I got tired of merging manifests

Comment: Change the API to 31 and use the latest compose version.

Comment: Use Kotlin 1.5.30 with the latest compose version. I tested it and it works.

Comment: as I said in bounty, it all works on empty project. please, read the post